# How to get HTML to Highlight in PHP file in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

I know this kind of question has been asked a few times but my situation is slightly different in that those questions were asked a while ago and the answers to them say that the issue would be fixed in a later release which are even previous to my version now: 2019.3.4

My code is below, followed by the screenshot of what it displays as in PhpStorm.

I have made sure that the *.html5 pattern is available for PHP files as well as trying `*.htm`, `*.html`, and finally `*.ht*`.

I didn't think it was a language injection problem as the entire HTML, no matter where it is, doesn't highlight but I check the rules anyway and there is one.

I also tried playing around with all the colour schemes but to no avail.

Just to clarify, HTML does highlight when in its own .html file.

```
<?php

    $testVar = "highlighting works";

    function allWorkingFine()
    {
        return "as you can see here";
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Highlighting</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>There is no highlighting for the HTML</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: PhpStorm Code Image]

Full Window Image:
[image: Full Window Image]

Comment: 1) Show whole IDE window please. At very least it show show that file visible in Project View panel as well as Editor Tab. Need to see file icon it uses. 2) Before that -- please disable ALL custom plugins (not bundled by default) and restart IDE.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I followed your instructions in your 2nd point but nothing changed. I also updated the post to include the screenshot for the full window.

Comment: You are using **a scratch file**. Place the same code in a file that is located inside the project folder -- it will work OK there. I'm not 100% sure if this is a bug or a feature (as scratch files have a bit less functionality/support from IDE in some aspects), but I do see similar thing in Twig files as well (only 1 primary language/syntax is supported in scratch files).

Comment: P.S. PhpStorm ticket for Twig file (similar behaviour: no syntax highlighting for HTML) -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress, just in case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51304

Comment: Thank you very much. I moved it into my own project folder and now it works. I guess it's just a scratch file thing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. How I solved this problem.

1. I deleted the ".idea" folder in the project folder (this folder belongs to php storm) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuNOG.png)
2. I reopened the project with Phpstorm.

After these two steps, everything was fine. You can also try this solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).